# Keep on having "Not a managed type: ..." error

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to learn SpringBootApplication and create like a simple app application that uses repository to perform CRUD operations with 'User' entities. For some reason I keep on having this error of

Not a managed type: class com.example.userApp.entities.User

I don't know why

This is the main function:

```
package com.example.userApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UserAppApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the repository function:

```
package com.example.userApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UserAppApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and here's the entity:
package com.example.userApp.entities;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    private String email;
    
}
```

I saw some threads that suggest using EntityScan, EnableJpaRepositories, and componentScan; I don't think they resolve the issue though

Comment: What version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: 3.0.5 i believe

Comment: Can you try to replace all `import javax.persistence.*` with `import jakarta.persistence.*`. If you are using Spring Boot 3.0.5 it now uses Jakarta instead of the javax imports

Comment: This helped tremendous!

Comment: I have added this is an answer you may accept to mark this as answered and help others find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 3.x (more specifically Spring Framework 6.x) changed from using Java EE to Jakarta EE (https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6), so your `javax.persistence.*` imports are no longer working. You need to replace them with `jakarta.persistence.*`